# Is there a comprehensive list of human circadian-like processes, hormones or gene expressions?

Tags: human-biology, endocrinology, circadian-rhythms

I'm reading this article on[blood sugar and circadian rhythms](http://med.stanford.edu/ism/2009/october/glucocorticoids.html) and the following question popped into my head: a lot of articles mention various diurnal or circadian rhythmicity of biological processes. **Is there a "master" list of hormones, gene expressions and other processes that the modern science recognizes as "circadian"?**

In other words, is there something that can give reader a clear picture of what's happening at a certain (biological)time for a human and is expected to happen tomorrow at similar time?

It would be great to take a look at such list and see what are the major processes that recur on a time-sensitive basis in humans.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a central/master website that I'm aware of, as it's still an area of active research.  I did a bit of work in the field about 10 years ago, and at that point we were still working out the circadian rhythms in the yeast mating cycle.

Since then, the field been enumerating more and more involved processes: mRNA expression, mRNA degradation, micro RNA, mRNA transport and translational regulation, then protein translation and protein regulation... Given that any single gene can be regulated at one or more of these points, and that there are at least a few different circadian cycles and they can even conflict... well, it's a bit of a mess.  Oh, and don't forget that different organs and cell types have different responses, so then you have to cross check 50 cell types.

I'd start with this review paper, which can give you an idea of what kinds of papers to search for.  If you decide you want to know about individual genes, a lot of scientists in the field have made their datasets available online in various gene expression databases.  There are several databases running currently, and maybe one of them will be specialized in circadian expression.

Circadian topology of metabolism
Joseph Bass
Nature 491, 348–356 (15 November 2012) doi:10.1038/nature11704
Published online 14 November 2012
http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v491/n7424/full/nature11704.html